# how to create different images for different screens

Tags: android, screen, styling

I created image only in 72x72 px. How can I add this picture to intellij idea with different sizes. Maybe is this work in photoshop?

how to create different images for different screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellij can't create your image for other densities. However, you can use this photoshop plugin : http://www.cutandslice.me/

Answer (score 1):

if you have problem with displaying in different screen size you should read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html